# to create csv file and append data according into the column if name of the file is same

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

My data is generated row wise using the separator "," and csv file is created and appended.i have four columns my data looks:

```
Image   Maxval   locx  locy
123.jpg  0.99     56     78
223.jpg  0.95     54     71
221.jpg  0.93     54     77
123.jpg  0.92     66     77
223.jpg  0.94     56     79
221.jpg  0.97     57     72
```

Now if the image name is same then I want to append the data in columns so it should look like

```
Image   Maxval   locx  locy   Maxval  locx   locy
123.jpg  0.99     56     78    0.92     66     77
223.jpg  0.95     54     71    0.94     56     79
221.jpg  0.93     54     77    0.97     57     72
```

Here I am confused wheather I should use dataframes or some csv function.

[image]
The photo shows the column Maxval_1 is sorted but other columns Maxval_2, maxval_3 and Maxval_4 are not

Comment: Using @anky_91 it worked but before the data was sorted now its not

Comment: added `.reindex(df.Image.unique()` to the same code , it now meets the expected output

Comment: @anky_91 it sorts only the first part , it sorts only Maxval_1 not Maxval_2, maxval_3 and Maxval_4

Comment: @anky_91 I tried m.columns.sort_values('Maxval',ascending=False) but it didnt worked.

Comment: I am not following, the expected output and the output generated by my code are same. when you say not sorted, can you explain a little. Thank you

Comment: inthe below output provided by you by using reindex code it sorted according to the column Maxval_1 but the other columns Maxval_2 is not sorted (I want Maxval columns in descending order)

Comment: But in the expected output Maxval_2 is not sorted in descending order. My code reorders all columns based on the Image ID which is the index in the order on the original dataframe

Comment: i have edited the question and added the photo i want all the Maxval_i columns to be sorted in descending order. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197670/discussion-between-anky-91-and-krupali-mistry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to assign a key `k` and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
m=(df.assign(k=(df.groupby('Image').Maxval.cumcount()+1))
.set_index(['Image','k']).unstack().sort_values('k',axis=1).reindex(df.Image.unique())
m.columns=['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in m.columns]
print(m)
```

---

```
         Maxval_1  locx_1  locy_1  Maxval_2  locx_2  locy_2
Image                                                      
123.jpg      0.99      56      78      0.92      66      77
223.jpg      0.95      54      71      0.94      56      79
221.jpg      0.93      54      77      0.97      57      72
```

Comment: and I want to store them back to csv file, how to do that

Comment: It worked but my data was soreted now its not, how?

Comment: @KrupaliMistry just add `.reindex(df.Image.unique())` , updated my code

Comment: @anky_91 in the first line of your code, `Maxval` is not needed right? we can `cumcount` directly on the column `Image`. Just trying to understand how the solution is working.

Comment: @mohansys,correct.i forgot to edit after some testing. I Will in sometime

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option store them as a list of values always keep appending to the list as using the same column name is not advised while storing as a `CSV` file